# How to do a nested select in where clause, in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Consider the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT  tfd.[ID],
        tfd.[TaxFormID],
        tfd.[TaxCodeLineNumber],
        tfd.[TaxCodeLineDescription]
FROM    [TaxCode].[TaxFormDetail] tfd
WHERE   tfd.[TaxFormID] = (SELECT TOP 1 cri.[TaxFormID] FROM [settings].[CompanyReportInformation] cri)
```

The database has one record in the "cri" table and I would like to do a top one record just as a mater of precaution.

I have the following LINQ statement that does not work and is where I need the help.

```
var _query = (
from tfd in TaxFormDetails
where tfd.TaxFormID ==
(from cri in CompanyReportInformation select new {cri.TaxFormID}).Take(1)
select new {tfd.ID, tfd.TaxFormID, tfd.TaxCodeLineNumber, tfd.TaxCodeLineDescription});
_query.Dump();
```

I get the following error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid?' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

What do I need to do to my LINQ statement to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... select cri.TaxFormID).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're wrapping your inner select into an anonymous type:

```
 select new {cri.TaxFormID}
```

should be

```
 select cri.TaxFormID
```

Comment: Made the change and now LinqPad is reporting the following error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid?' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Guid?>'`